# Laravel livewire: use as a laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-livewire

I use in my app to do instant searches. indeed I displayed the establishment's with its files which are displayed in my **controller show** as follows:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $etablissements = Etablissement::find($id);
    $faculty = $etablissements->filieres;
    return view('etablissements/edhec/touteslesfilieresedhec', compact('faculty','etablissements'));
}
```

now i tried to do the same in my livewire component in order to be able to do a search as follows:

```
class SchoolfaclutysList extends Component
{
  public $faculty;
  public function mount($id)
{
    $etablissements = Etablissement::find($id);
    $this->faculty = $etablissements->filieres;
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.schoolfaclutys-list');
}
}
```

but he returns the empty page to me
**view blade**

```
<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <a href="{{ route('filiere.show', ['filiere' => $etablissements->id]) }}" class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-pill mr-3 font-weight-bold text_info">Informations générales</a>
            <a href="{{ route('filieresedhec') }}" class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-pill ml-5 font-weight-bold text_filière">Filières/Facultés</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @livewire('schoolfaclutys-list')
  </div>
  <!-- Debut footer -->
    @include('layouts/partials/_footer')
  <!-- Fin footer -->
```

**web-php**

```
route::resource('school','schoolController');
```

is it possible to make it work as a laravel controller? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use "model route binding" to pass in the instance of your model directly into the construct, which in Livewire is the `mount()` method.

```php
Route::get('school/{etablissement}', \App\Http\Livewire\SchoolfaclutysList::class)->name('school.show');
```

Then you declare both the variables you need in your Blade-view as ***public*** properties on the class. Only public properties on the class will be passed into the blade (or those that is passed via the `data` parameter to the `view()` method in the `render()` method).

```php
class SchoolfaclutysList extends Component
{
    public $faculty;
    public $etablissement;

    public function mount(Etablissement $etablissement)
    {
        $this->etablissement = $etablissement;
        $this->faculty = $this->etablissement->filieres;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.schoolfaclutys-list');
    }
}
```

Comment: It brings me back this error `App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Livewire\SchoolfaclutysList was not found`. au niveau de ma route i use laravel 7

Comment: Do you have a namespace around a group where that route is defined?